# Problem with WordPress and Google Cloud Platform

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform

I deployed my site under Google Cloud, transferred my domain over to Google Domains from GoDaddy, and followed the steps in setting up DNS Cloud.

Now that I can't log-in to my temporary WordPress site to continue working on it as well as my domain right now showing some errors (after following the steps from DNS Cloud, I also want to revert the step where it tells me to put an HTML code as "Hello World!" to verify if I do it right).

Any helps is appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please consider reading this article [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please provide more information about your steps: **1**. How many hours ago you changed DNS setting for your domain? Can you provide your domain name? **2**. What do you mean by "can't log-in to my temporary WordPress site", "showing some errors " and "revert the step where it tells me to put an HTML code"?

Comment: Hi Serhii! I managed to sort this out with the GCP support team regarding the DNS setting, the only issue now is I want to revert the step which I followed here: https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/tutorials/create-domain-tutorial#set-up-domain (Step 3.2) where they told me to overwrite the default webpage with the "Hello World!" HTML, so that my actual website will show, not that title.

Comment: You should replace `/var/www/html/index.html` your original file.

Comment: Can you show me how can I perform this command?

Comment: Have you deployed your site from scratch on Google Cloud or copied it from somewhere?

Comment: I deployed it from scratch on GCP.

Comment: Too bad, it looks like you don't have a backup. Could you provide more details how you deployed Wordpress?

Comment: Hi Serhii, I managed to get the support from Google Cloud team and they told me to perform a sudo command line in SSH terminal, it's all good now. Thanks for your time I really appreciated it!

Comment: Thanks! Could you post an answer with brief description of the problem and solution from Google Support?

Comment: Hi Serhii, they told me to perform this command line: sudo rm index.html and boom, my site is back without the "Hello World" embedded to it (from following step 3.2 in setting up DNS Cloud). Took me a couple of days to reach the right person for the job! But I'm thankful for all helps and advice I got along the way!

Answer (score 0):

This issue was solved by [Google Cloud Support](https://cloud.google.com/support) by running this command:

```
sudo rm index.html
```

After that site is back without the "Hello World" embedded to it (from following step 3.2 in setting up DNS Cloud).